# Critique My Codeigniter Custom CMS Pages Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

I am currently developing a custom CMS being built on top of Codeigniter and was wondering if you can spot any flaws in my page fetching model code. The page fetching model is not entirely complete but the main functionality for retrieving a page is done, as well as retrieving modules assigned to a page (a module is really just a widget).

Can this model be better in some parts, perhaps in relation to the joins I am doing? although not really joins, but multiple queries to pull out bits of related info the pages like modules and media.

```
<?php

  class Mpages extends CI_Model {

      public function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
      }

      public function fetch_page($page_slug = 'home') 
      {
          $db = $this->db;

          $query = 
            $db
               ->where('page_status', 1)
               ->where('page_slug', strtolower($page_slug))
               ->get('pages')
               ->result_array();

          $page_id = $query[0]['id'];

          $query['modules'] = 
            $db
                ->select('modules.module_name, modules.module_slug, modules.id moduleid')
                ->where('page_id', $page_id)
                ->join('pages_modules lpm', 'moduleid = lpm.module_id')
                ->order_by('module_order', 'asc')
                ->get('modules')
                ->result_array();

          /*$query['media'] = 
            $db
                ->select('lucifer_media.media_file_name, lucifer_media.media_file_extension, lucifer_media.media_directory')
                ->join('lucifer_pages_media', 'lucifer_pages_media.page_id = '.$page_id.'')
                ->get('lucifer_media')
                ->result_array();*/

          if ($query) {

            return $query;

          } else {
            return false;
          }
      }

      public function fetch_navigation()
      {
        $result = $this->db->order_by("nav_order", "asc")->where('published', 1)->get('navigation')->result_array();
        return $result;
      }

      public function fetch_layout($id)
      {

          $result = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('layouts')->result_array();

          return $result[0];

      }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aaaah, a CodeIgniter fella :-)

I'm just working on a CI project myself and already implemented some of the **optimization** you could use for your CMS as well... so let's have a look:

1. for as little **overhead** as possible, try implementing **lazy-loading** of your files (libraries, models...)
2. for **caching** purposes, you can use KHCache - a library that allows you to cache parts of the website instead of full page
3. instead of always doing $this->db->..., you can create a **helper function**, for instance "function _db()" and then simply do _db()->where...
4. also, you can optionally create a helper function to give you the **results array** automatically, so ->result_array() will not be neccessary anymore: function res() {} ... $query = res(_db()->where...);

---

now, for the **code** :-)

```
$query = 
    $db
      ->where('page_status', 1)
      ->where('page_slug', strtolower($page_slug))
      ->get('pages')
      ->result_array();

$page_id = $query[0]['id'];
```

here, you seem to be selecting **all values from DB**, while in need of a single first ID - try limiting number of results or this will create overhead in your database

```
$db->where...->limit(1);
```

---

the second query could probably use a **LEFT JOIN** instead of a regular JOIN, although I leave it to you to decide (the JOIN approach might not list everything you need)

```
$db-select...->join('pages_modules lpm', 'moduleid = lpm.module_id', 'left')
```

---

I guess that's all... just remember to put correct **indexes** on your SQL fields and use the **EXPLAIN** statement to check for bottlenecks

***good luck!***

Comment: and since I can't post links in answers due to low rating, here they are - lazy load: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/134605/

Comment: you can find KHCache here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/69843/

Comment: and at last, EXPLAIN statement from MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html ... I'd be delighted if you accepted this answer if you found it useful, so I can get rid of these link limitations :-D

Comment: instead of a helper function why not `$db =& $this->db` and then do `$db->select()...`

Comment: Robert - to save time... _db()->select is quicker and requires only 1 line of code, while as with your solution, you need to write more of the same code every time (which could also change in the future, so you'd need to do extensive search/replaces in all files)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Codeigniter so i can't comment on "is this a propper model". For my answer i'm just going to assume it is.

It's not much code so i'm going to focus on some details:

---

```
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }
```

Those 5 lines do absolutely nothing. I'd remove them. If you need a constructor later, add it later.

---

```
  public function fetch_navigation()
  {
    $result = $this->db->order_by("nav_order", "asc")->where('published', 1)->get('navigation')->result_array();
    return $result;
  }
```

This is a pretty hard to read (113 Chars in that line). I'd go for something like this (to say with your formatting from above)

```
  public function fetch_navigation()
  {
      return $this->db
          ->order_by("nav_order", "asc")
          ->where('published', 1)
          ->get('navigation')
          ->result_array();
  }
```

---

```
$db = $this->db;
```

Seems unnecessary to create a local variable, those 6 extra chars shoudn't hurt. I needed to look twice to see where that variable is from and if its local because changes are made to it.

---

So far those are really minor notes.

### Unreachable code ?

```
if ($query) {
  return $query;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

you are setting `$query['modules'] = ...` so even if that is null $query will at least contain

```
array("modules" => null);
```

and that will always be true.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time and effort to post a solution. As for the constructor, you need that to interface with the parent controller of the Codeigniter framework, otherwise I do believe you can't use pre-loaded libraries, models and other things loaded automatically in the core. Valid point about $this->db though. I've always done that, but have also wondered if assigning it to a $db variable was worth the extra effort and convoluted things. Thanks for the modules null tip as well.

Comment: Erm, `$db =& $this->db;` would be more beneficial would it not?

Comment: @RobertPitt Doing thats might be even harmful. Objects are passed "as reference" anyways and are hurtful php in general. There are only some very special cases where there is -any- benefit in using them

Comment: @Dwayne If you just leave the lines out the constructor of the parent class will be called by php. The only thing that you shoudn't to is leave it completely empty (thats also why i don't like "always having an constructor" someone might leave it blank and break stuff

Comment: @edorian, I believe that objects are only passed by reference as of PHP 5.2.0, as Codeigniter are sticking with the support of PHP 4 within CI 2.0, I think I was just sticking with the application standards in suggesting that.

Comment: @RobertPitt Juding from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php this happed with the PHP 5.0 release - I don't have access quick to an really old 5.1.6 to test it but i'm pretty sure :) If not please let me know

Comment: My apologies, i had got that information from a comment on the php site, so i had taken it was specifically that release, after readong some Zend papers i can see that it was part of the big release in 5.0. +1

Comment: Great info guys, really insightful stuff. I ditched assigning the $this->db to a $db variable, didn't seem worth it to be honest. I want to keep my code as clean and efficient as possible.

Comment: @Dwayne, Keeping code clean starts here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Robert. I know of the Zend standard of coding style and conventions because I have to use it at work unfortunately. Here is the link to the Codeigniter style documentation, not as long, but still concise: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html